# Communication of one directive with a bunch of others at runtime

Tags: angularjs, runtime, communication, directive

I have created a 'A' directive control. There would be more than one of those on page. There is an other control 'B' on the page that would need to communicate with 'A' type of directives but only one at a time i.e., the one which is selected (like play/stop video in that control). Since new to angularjs world, I am not really sure if its possible to do this and how should it be done. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Imad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main question is - are all the A directives contained in a B directive?

If the answer is yes, you can register the A directives in B's controller, like in angular's example for tabs:

http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

The part to note there is how they use `require: '^tabs'` in A's directive to access B's controller. In your use case, I guess that once an A instance is selected, it should tell it to B's controller in its link function.

If the answer is no, you can create a service (called S for example) in which the two directives will communicate through. This time, B will register in S for changes. When an A instance is selected, it will tell it to service S, and B's callback should be invoked.

Comment: Thanks haimlit for useful ideas. It appeared that my usecase was not very complex and having one directive contained inside other would work for me.